# gulp-replace replaces the css string only the first time, even if I run it by hand many times

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace

the first time I run gulp it will change lets say cb=123 to cb=1607263938392 (this is the new Date().getTime()) but afterwards even I run it hundred times by hand running gulp, it will not change. If I delete a couple of digits it will replace the string again. I noticed that when the digits are exactly 13 it doesn't replace them. I run it by hand without a watch.

```js
const { src, series, parallel, dest, watch } = require('gulp');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');

function replaceHtml() {
    var cbString = 'cb='+new Date().getTime();
    
    return src(["index.html"])
      .pipe(replace(/cb=\d+/g, function() {
        return cbString;
      }))
      .pipe(dest("."));
  }

exports.default = replaceHtml;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?cb=1607263938392">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied your code and it updates each time as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i finally found out that the problem was that vscode did not update the file. it updated only if the characters were less or more than already in the file.
btw I am using vscode 1.51.1 (debian version) on linux.
I did a cat index.html and I show that the file was changing.
it was really driving me nuts!!!
thanks a lot Mark for your reply

Comment: I'm on Windows10, so maybe it is a vscode on linux issue.  Also, you might try sending the file to a different directory or filename rather than over-writing the same file to see if it makes any difference.